# Dimension of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a vector space. Let $U = \left\{(x, y, z)\in V \colon x+y+z=0\right\}$ and $W=\left\{(x,y,z)\in V\colon x-2y+z=0\right\}$ be subspaces of $V$. Find the dimension of the subspace $U+W$. Now $U+W=\left\{(x,y,z)\in V\colon 2x-y+2z=0\right\}$. How do I find the dimension of this?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong in assuming that
$$
U+W=\{(x,y,z)\in V\colon 2x-y+2z=0\}
$$
It simply doesn't work like this. For instance, $(1,1,-2)\in U$, but
$$
2\cdot 1-1+2\cdot(-2)\ne0
$$
so $(1,1,-2)\notin\{(x,y,z)\in V\colon 2x-y+2z=0\}$, while $U\subseteq U+W$.

In order to solve this exercise, you have to find bases of $U$ and $W$, put them together and reduce the resulting set to a linearly independent set that spans the same subspace.

A basis of $U$ consists of the vectors $(1/2,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$. Why? The equation $x=\frac{1}{2}y-z$ has two free variables and you get a basis of the subspace by choosing first $y=1,z=0$ and then $y=0,z=1$.

Similarly, a basis for $W$ consists of the vectors $(2,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$.

Now consider the matrix having the four vectors as columns and perform Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 2 & -3 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -3/2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -3/2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3/2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -3/2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
We thus see that the first three columns are linearly independent and so a basis of $U+W$ is given by
$$
\{(1/2,1,0),(-1,0,1),(2,1,0)\}
$$
By the way, this means that $U+W=V$, because it has dimension $3$.

One could also noticing this directly, because it's apparent that $(2,1,0)\notin U$, so $U+W$ is a subspace properly containing $U$; but $U$ has dimension $2$, so $U+W$ has dimension at least $3$, that is, it is $V$. However, the method outlined before is completely general.

Note also that, by the dimension formula,
$$
\dim(U\cap W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U+W)=2+2-3=1
$$
Since obviously $(-1,0,1)\in U\cap W$, we also have a basis for the intersection.